# Установка WAT для Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Пытаюсь установить в MVS это дополнение: http://wat.codeplex.com/
Выдаёт ошибку "Это расширение не может быть установлено ни для одного из установленных продуктов".

В чём может быть ошибка? На сайте написано что нужна Win 8.1, у меня ни на 8.1, ни на 10 не ставится, может MVS бесплатная потому что? На сколько я знаю шаблон можно установить на любой выше 2013г.
Кто-нибудь разбирается?:)

Comment: лог инсталяции откройте, там и будет ответ на ваш вопрос, у меня на русскую ентерпрайз 2015 под 2012R2 вставать отказалась

Comment: Почему-то всё оказалось проще, чем предполагалось.
В логе и правда точные версии указаны, которые не совпадают. Блин. Пробую переустановить. Спасибо:)

Comment: А вы, Дмитрий, я так понял, работаете с WAT? Я, если вы не против, задал бы ещё один вопрос по теме:)

Comment: я работаю с MVC :) мне было интересно почему у вас не работает и я проверил :)

Comment: Чёртов WAT, никто не знает как этим пользоваться.:) В эмуляторе программа работает, а скомпилировать не получается, для запуска вне MVS.